Killing-free worlds promoting goodness though love and animals and their situation
I wanted to ask this question on philosophy stack exchange.
Suppose a person is trying to promote the idea that it is wrong to kill and use love to promote the idea that people must think that the world is good.
Now, suppose, one has to consider animals. Some animals are carnivores, and, must kill to live.
Now, assume, that animals are included into the picture.
One must advocate feeding carnivore animals lab meat.
However, lab meat commercialization is not near complete.
This means, that, one must live in an imperfect world where in order to advocate good, they must also not think about some things (like, that some animals are killed to feed carnivores or that some animals eat other animals).
This, leads, to an imperfect world (where, in order to promote good, you must not think about some things).
This, would be (to the best of my knowledge), ... a world that can improve, but where perfection can only be attained though intelligence and insightfulness, ... perhaps, some new scientific discoveries, or, illuminations, ... will reach us.
I wanted to ask on the philosophy stack exchange... how do you confront this problem?
Thanks.

"I wanted to ask this question on philosophy stack exchange" - why didn't you? This is Meta, which is for questions about how the Philosophy site works, about site policy, posting bugs, requesting features, etc. If you want to know whether some question would fit on the main site, you could ask a more general question about what the policy is around those types of questions. If you're unable to post on the main site for some reason, asking on Meta instead is not appropriate. Although [chat] is also an option.


Suppose a person is trying to promote the idea...

Not sure if that's the question, but promoting ideas is not the purpose of this site, the purpose is to ask about literature of philosophers. Reactions to attempts to promote can be mixed.
We already have these questions: Resource request for philosophical arguments regarding the ethics of killing animals
Is there an ethical basis for killing less intelligent animals (as food) but not killing animals of higher intelligence?
Should animals be ethically considered?
How can animals be objects of ethics without being subjects as well?
Philosophical justification for giving certain animals rights of a person?
What are the earliest advocates for animal rights and/or moral equivalency between killing animals Vs. Killing humans?
Responsibility for animals as human and does it undermine true equality?
Have philosophers neglected human obligations to other animals?
What is the meat paradox?
These questions and their answers might help with the issue in general and with how to ask questions on such topics.

AFAIC this is suitable for main and you should ask this there.
That said:

There is a brawl in progress right now on which/who/why/how questions-closure. And there's a good chance this (kind of) question will be closed (especially now).
While I think it's a good question, I don't have a good pointed answer.
A vague generic answer would be:
You are thinking most likely of Christian love. (This is the normal framing out here).
Try a different variant eg. Buddhist or Hindu or Nietzsche. The question will change significantly.


Personal note: I'm an unwilling non-vegetarian.

You are asking a question from the POV of Love Virtue, one of the three higher virtues of Virtue Ethics.
The basic answer is that our world is not structured such that Love Virtue is exemplified in nature.
Living things are structured such that they multiply beyond their food supply, and are basically forced into conflict.  They consume each other, or cordon off food from rivals such that rivals starve. Or poison/shade out rivals (plant vs plant behavior).  That some animals can ONLY eat meat -- carnivores -- exemplifies this issue.
Love virtue basically calls for us to try to extend love and empathy to all other living things.
BUT -- we have inadequate resources, as either individuals, or as a society, to do this.  The limitations of human intervention, such trying to make all carnivores wards of the state, fed by lab grown meat, is just one illustration of the problem.
This problem is not limited to Virtue Ethics.  Utilitarians face the same one.  The welfare of starving mice, under Peter Singer's animal liberation ethics, are of equal value to that of starving humans.  And one's well-fed children, when mice are starving in the lawn outside one's house in winter -- is a much as a moral quandary as the inability to feed one's pet carnivores on grain.
Rights ethics if applied narrowly can at least limit rights to negative rights -- and dismiss the starving mice as "not my fault" and rationalize ones hands are clean.  BUT -- every planted and harvested field of grain kills multitudes of small rodents -- so even negative rights thinking faces this problem.
Our living world is such that it cannot be made ethical.
The realization of this has major implications for theistic moral theory (no monotheism can be made compatible with omnibenevolence, because any monotheistic God could remake the world, and has not done so).
For personal morality, which is what you asked about, it has a different consequence. One simply cannot live by a fully moral value set.  One must compromise any moral guidelines with some degree of self-interest, and self-forgiveness.  How much -- I have yet to see any coherent answer.  But each moral thinker has to find some way to limit the constraints of moral obligation.
As tkruse points out, asking "what do you think" questions, or "is this wrong" questions are not accepted here.  BUT, one can ask "how have philosophers addressed problem X". I urge you to ask a modified question on the main philosophy site, asking how animal rights advocates and theoreticians deal with our inability to achieve moral control of the living world.
